# Debian, OpenSUSE freeze dead on boot with an ATI GPU

Tags: boot, freeze

I'm trying to install Debian or OpenSUSE on a 2012 laptop (to be honest, it's not bad). I succeeded installing both, but both of them freeze dead a couple of seconds after booting.

Because I installed Debian without DM, it gave me a clue about the cause for hanging:

```
*error* radeon ring 0 test failed
```

This happens right before it gives the tty to login (and then, in 1-5 seconds it freezes).

All I found about this problem is [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457391/radeon-ring-0-test-failed-on-boot-ubuntu-14-04), which suggested a solution to disable the discrete GPU. I'd like to have it as the last option and want to know if there are better ways.

More info about what's going on:

- CPU: Intel, 64bit
- UEFI is supported
- I have to disable ACPI because otherwise OpenSUSE installation gets stuck at "Loading basic drivers"
- I have to disable UEFI because if I enable it, it won't give me option to disable ACPI (don't ask, no clue)
- There's no Secure Boot option in the BIOS of this laptop
- Sometimes OpenSUSE doesn't even get to boot. Instead, my monitor starts flickering (on and off, on and off, etc.) infinitely

So, my question is, is there some easy way to fix this freezing? Maybe by getting proprietary drivers? Or something else? Or the problem is not related to GPU? I'm afraid my problem is generic and not specific to Debian and OpenSUSE...

Edit: there's another issue: during installation both keep disconnecting from Wi-Fi. Basically they ask for network configuration, I input ssid/encryption/password, they connect... and then, once they ask about online repositories, by that time it's already disconnected from wifi... for some reason

Edit2: both OpenSUSE and Debian work in live mode.

Comment: Google for your laptop brand and model + "linux".   Since you haven't bothered telling us what your laptop is, the most we can say is "laptops are often weird. manufacturers tend to cut corners and do weird things just to shoehorn a PC into a tiny portable case and they also tend to build them as disposable junk on a 12-ish month upgrade churn cycle - not quite as bad as the phone/tablet cycle but close".

Comment: This is a Samsung laptop. According to dmidecode, Product name is "700Z3A/700Z4A/700Z5A/700Z5B". I don't see any screaming issues on the internet with this laptop. Also you may have not seen this (I edited the post recently), but both OpenSUSE and Debian work  from live usb.

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick solution

Now, regarding this issue. Like I said, while installing Tumbleweed I disabled ACPI. So being about to give up I tried running Debian by [changing the kernel parameters to disable acpi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting). And... it just worked.

If this solution worked for you, you can proceed to a more fundamental solution.

#### Why it is perhaps not a good idea

ACPI provides power interface, so [don't expect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189327/how-to-check-battery-status-when-acpi-is-off) battery level and suspend function to work.

#### Update: A better solution

It is much better to disable the gpu only. [Here's how](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771562/16-04-power-off-discrete-graphics-ati-amd). Now ACPI works, but GPU doesn't freeze the laptop.