# Cannot boot into Debian, OpenSUSE Tumbleweed: infinite turning off and on

Tags: boot, grub

I tried installing both Debian and OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, but didn't manage to boot in either of those. Basically, here's what happens, when I turn on PC to boot from hard drive:

1. Turn on PC
2. Monitor turns on
3. No welcome message from grub
4. No error
5. **Then it turns off and on infinitely**

While in this loop, I can press Escape and it would get me to the boot menu of bios (not to bios' main menu, but to another one). That gives me a hint that I have problems with booting.

I tried it with both OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and Debian. I also tried with installing grub on both btrfs, ext4, and its own partition. All the same identical issue.

I also *managed* to boot into Debian once, which I cannot reproduce now, but I used [**super grub**](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/) for it. So I *guess* it means that the bootloader is the problem. But... how? What am I doing wrong?

Some info:

- Laptop is Samsung 700Z[something] from 2012
- No other OS is installed on this laptop (and whenever installing, I formatted the disk)
- CPU is Intel, 32 bit
- GPU is ATI (AMD), but the CPU has AFAIK also an integrated GPU

There's also a problem with getting into the system *after* booting [due to some GPU driver problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716790/debian-opensuse-freeze-dead-on-boot-with-an-ati-gpu), so I have at least two barriers to getting into the system now (and I don't really understand why it's so hard).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, finally. Basically, whenever I installed both of them, I used manual partitioning. Instead, the last installation I used "Guided - Use the entire disk" and it worked. The reasons for failure were either:

- That I accidentally, all these times, set swap to primary and it tried to boot from it
- Or that it installed it into GPT partition table, and I didn't have a partition for it.

So in the end, using the guided partitioning helped me and grub worked.