# Enable ATI GPU work on debian 11

Tags: freeze, amd, radeon, ati

I'm on an old laptop with AMD ATI Radeon 6490 M. With default kernel parameters any Linux [freezes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716790/debian-opensuse-freeze-dead-on-boot-with-an-ati-gpu) on booting, which I fixed by disabling the discrete AMD gpu completely:

```
radeon.modeset=0 amdgpu.runpm=0 acpi_backlight=intel_blacklight
```

It makes it boot, but I want the GPU to work (mainly because I want to unload the CPU and perhaps the battery will last longer?).

This

```
radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1
```

doesn't help either: it still freezes exactly the same way.

[This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ATI#Installation) arch wiki suggestion to install `mesa` didn't change anything either, still freezes.

I also tried pulling the driver from [my exact GPU official webpage](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-6000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-6490m), but it gives error something like "the driver only supports X server versions 6.9 to 1.10, yours is 1.20".

Any idea how to make it actually work?

Comment: If it doesn't work with kernel 6.0.2 you may want to file a bug report here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues

Comment: I'm on 5.10.0-18-amd64 (that's what is shiped with debian 11 stable). Should I upgrade the kernel?

Comment: FWIW I tried 6.0.2 and the problem is the same

Comment: File a bug report please. It's also possible your GPU is faulty.

Comment: [filed](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2214), but I still think that it's my issue and not theirs, to be honest